# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID has already been found in the view. happened with a selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf

In my view I have a `selectOneMenu`as shown in the following code:

```
   <h:panelGroup id="mysrvicenodesblock" layout="block">
     <table id="mysrvicenodestab" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
          <td align="center" class="underline">node Id</td>
          <td align="center" class="underline">node Name</td>
          <td align="center" class="underline">Go to node</td>                                  
          <td align="center" class="underline">Action</td>
        </tr>
      <c:forEach items="${jbpmAPIUtil.myServiceNodeToComplete}" var="msntoc">
        <tr>
          <td align="center">${msntoc.getId()}</td>
          <td align="center">${msntoc.getName()}</td>
          <td align="center">
         <h:selectOneMenu value="#{jbpmAPIUtil.procNdNameSelectedValue}" id="procnodes">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{jbpmAPIUtil.procnodes}" var="pn"  itemLabel="# {pn.getName()}" itemValue="#{pn.getId()}" />
<f:ajax event="change" listener="#{jbpmAPIUtil.OnONeMenuProcNdSelChgeHndler}" />
             </h:selectOneMenu>
          </td>                                     
          <td align="center">                                               
          <h:commandLink value="Complete !">
             <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{jbpmAPIUtil.Completemsn}">
             </f:ajax>                                             <f:param value="${msntoc.getWorkitemid()}" name="msntocwiid"/>
                                                 </h:commandLink>
 </td>             


     </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</h:panelGroup>
```

This component is contained on a `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` which is refreshed periodically with a primefaces `p:poll`.

The bean used for binding this element's  values is a session scoped bean (i dont know if this is also called "binding" there is not a "binding" attribute on this component).

I've read in many posts that this problem happens becose the bean and the view have different scopes but I remember I've been in such as situation alot times without this problem have been occured.

I wish to know exactly which binding have caused this problem and is there other solution to avoid this problem to happen.

this is the full stack for this problem which happens when i click the commandLink button so the table with the foreach loop content will change (one row will be deleted and 2 others added to the list)

```
SEVERE: +id: j_id1
 type: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@c0fee0
  +id: javax_faces_location_HEAD
   type: com.sun.faces.component.ComponentResourceContainer@5be0a8
    +id: j_id2
     type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@1fa3bee
    +id: j_id3
     type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@174b989
    +id: j_id4
     type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@40f2f1
  +id: j_idt2
   type: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

  +id: j_idt3
   type: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  +id: j_idt4
   type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@dd874
    +id: j_idt5
     type: 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/general.css"/>

<script src="JS/jquery-1.8.3.js"/>
<script src="JS/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js"/>
<script src="JS/jquerygen.js"/>
<script src="JS/general.js"/>


    <title>Xtensus Workflow App </title>



  +id: j_idt6
   type: 

<body>

  +id: j_idt7
   type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm@fdc98d
    +id: j_idt8
     type: 

<div id="ctrldiv">

Id du noeud actuel (le curseur jbpm) : 
    +id: niid
     type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1bb55d3
    +id: j_idt9
     type: <br/>
Nom du noeud actuel (le curseur jbpm) : 
    +id: cnn
     type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1ff95a9
    +id: j_idt10
     type: <br/>




    +id: j_idt11
     type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandLink@baa6f7
    +id: j_idt12
     type: 


<br/>       


<br/>

<H3>#Noeuds en cours d'execution : </H3>
<div>

    +id: mysrvicenodesblock
     type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGroup@27d9e5
      +id: j_idt13
       type: 
                            <table id="mysrvicenodestab" border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" class="underline">node Id</td>
                                    <td align="center" class="underline">node Name</td>
                                    <td align="center" class="underline">Go to node</td>                                    
                                    <td align="center" class="underline">Action</td>
                                </tr>

      +id: j_idt18
       type: 
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">${msntoc.getId()}</td>
                                        <td align="center">${msntoc.getName()}</td>
                                        <td align="center">


      +id: procnodes
       type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneMenu@527386
        +id: j_idt19
         type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItem@11e7e46
        +id: j_idt20
         type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems@f45673
      +id: j_idt21
       type: 

                                        </td>                                       
                                        <td align="center">                                               

      +id: j_idt22
       type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandLink@157be76
        +id: j_idt23
         type: javax.faces.component.UIParameter@1996e15
      +id: j_idt24
       type: 
                                        </td>             


                                    </tr>

      +id: j_idt25
       type: 
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">${msntoc.getId()}</td>
                                        <td align="center">${msntoc.getName()}</td>
                                        <td align="center">


      +id: procnodes
       type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneMenu@a5adc
        +id: j_idt27
         type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItem@1d34eac
        +id: j_idt28
         type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems@1d20651
      +id: j_idt29
       type: 

                                        </td>                                       
                                        <td align="center">                                               

      +id: j_idt30
       type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandLink@19cee52
        +id: j_idt31
         type: javax.faces.component.UIParameter@1e27046
      +id: j_idt32
       type: 
                                        </td>             


                                    </tr>

      +id: j_idt33
       type: 
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">${msntoc.getId()}</td>
                                        <td align="center">${msntoc.getName()}</td>
                                        <td align="center">


      +id: procnodes
       type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneMenu@1391a2c
        +id: j_idt35
         type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItem@1e54eb7
        +id: j_idt36
         type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems@1930089
      +id: j_idt37
       type: 

                                        </td>                                       
                                        <td align="center">                                               

      +id: j_idt38
       type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandLink@860ba
        +id: j_idt39
         type: javax.faces.component.UIParameter@664ca
      +id: j_idt40
       type: 
                                        </td>             


                                    </tr>

      +id: j_idt14
       type: 
                            </table>

    +id: j_idt15
     type: 
</div>      



</div>


    +id: j_idt16
     type: org.primefaces.component.poll.Poll@1c334de
  +id: j_idt17
   type: 
</body>
</html>

Mar 8, 2013 5:08:49 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID j_idt7:procnodes has already been found in the view.  
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:910)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:894)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:894)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletFullStateManagementStrategy.saveView(FaceletFullStateManagementStrategy.java:680)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:89)
    at javax.faces.application.StateManager.getViewState(StateManager.java:553)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.renderState(PartialViewContextImpl.java:416)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:300)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:981)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1770)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace?  When does this exception occur, when the poll ajax happens?  When the selectOneMenu value is changed?  Can you post the code for the poll as well?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention when the problem occurs, i ve edited my post for more details

Comment: Well, i resolved this problem by just deleting the id attribute on the  selectOneMenu component :), this wouldn't be a solution if i had to keep the id for referencing that component in the view.

Comment: The id, "procnodes", repeats in c:forEach. Use jsf datatable instead of table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<c:forEach>` JSTL does not by default increment the child ids of components within them.  You would either have to do this with EL expressions or use a JSF component better suited for iterating over a collection, like `UIRepeat`.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{jbpmAPIUtil.myServiceNodeToComplete}" var="msntoc">
```

The following component replacing the forEach component will properly iterate the ID's that are generated of components inside this, and this way duplicate ID's will not exist on the page.

NOTE: Just double check that you are using `<h:head>` instead of `<head>` and `<h:body>` instead of `<body>` on your page.  It looked suspicious to me in your stack trace that you might have other problems associated with that.

Comment: It s very interesting to know , thank U ! By the way i ve added a <f:param value="${msntoc.getWorkitemid()}" name="msntocwiid"/> inside the selectOneMenu but the value gotten on the server side was always null. Doesn't the selectOneMenu support the <f:param ??

Comment: @user1705922 It does, but `<h:commandLink>` doesn't respond to click events.  You need to remove the `listener` attribute from `<f:ajax>` and add it to `actionListener` of `<h:commandLink>`.  You can keep the `<f:ajax />` tag without attributes and it will work.

Comment: From which <f:ajax> should i remove the listener? Both commandLink and the selectOneMenu have different functionalities, i dont see the relation that have the CommandLink with the selectOneMenu component.

Comment: @user1705922 Oh I misunderstood.  That should work, but if you are using EL 2.2 then you can instead just pass msntoc as an argument to the action... `listener="#{jbpmAPIUtil.OnONeMenuProcNdSelChgeHndler(msntoc)}"`

Comment: Well, thank u again ,i didnt know this EL 2.2 feature's for passing parameters on method experssion, but i dont think i can do that on a managed bean listener handler method which should have only an AjaxBehaviorEvent as parameter.